# CAML query in Sharepoint using C# with IN and EQ operations

Tags: caml

I am new to CAML queries, stuck with the below option. I have a list ABC, with around 200000 records. I want to retrieve records based on 2 conditions:

1. IsDeleted = True (yes/no field with value=yes)
2. Title in ('200', '201', '202')

```
updstring "<Value Type='String'>200</Value><Value Type='String'>201</Value><Value Type='String'>202</Value>";

camlQuery2.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                                <Query> 
                                 <Where>
                                  <Eq>
                                   <FieldRef Name='IsDeleted' />
                                   <Value Type='Bool'>1</Value>
                                  </Eq>
                                  <And>
                                   <In>
                                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                                     <Values>" + updstring + @"</Values>
                                   </In>
                                  </And>
                                 </Where>
                                </Query>
                                <ViewFields>
                                 <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                                 <FieldRef Name='IsDeleted' />
                                </ViewFields>
                                <RowLimit Paged='TRUE'>" + rowLimit2 + "</RowLimit></View>";
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Regards,
Ganesh.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself..

This works. Actually the And tag needs to be placed at the top and the conditions for AND, such as Eq & In must be inside it. A bit different from regular SQL syntax of query writing. Thanks for pointing out Tyler2p, sorry I did not write the explanation.

```
                                  <Where>
                                  <And>
                                  <Eq>
                                   <FieldRef Name='IsDeleted' />
                                   <Value Type='Bool'>1</Value>
                                  </Eq>
                                  
                                   <In>
                                    <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                                     <Values>" + updstring + @"</Values>
                                   </In>
                                  </And>
                                 </Where>
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that any future readers can learn from it.